# How to remove this error and install this package on pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, numpy, pythonanywhere

Python Anywhere `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded`

I am installing `numpy==1.24.1` package on pythonanywhere bash and getting this error `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded`

Comment: You need more disk space. Delete something or upgrade your account.